# Why do we need tetrads/vierbeins/frame-fields to describe fermions in curved space?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, fermions, spinors, dirac-matrices

I'm learning about the frame formalism and read that to couple fermions to gravity you need to go to the frame-formalism.

As a motivation to learn more about frame-fields would someone sketch me why this is necessary? If possible give nice references.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161744/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161821/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lorentz group $O(3,1)$ has spinor representations (actually $SL(2,\mathbb C)$, that is the universal cover of $O(3,1)$), as well known. The problem is that now, in general relativity, we want to deal with generic transformations. So we are working with G$L(4)$.

Roughly speaking, the associated Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(4)$ doesn't admit spinor representations. See for instance: [No Spinor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121620/why-does-gln-have-no-spinor-representations) The way out is to go to a local inertial frame, in which you recover the flat space and you can define the spinors.

For supergravity I can suggest to you D. Freedman and A. V. Proeyen (Supergravity, 2012)