# Does $\operatorname{GL}(N,\mathbb{R})$ own spinor representation? Which group is its covering group? (Kaku's QFT textbook)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In Kaku's QFT textbook page 54, there is a saying:

> $\operatorname{GL}(N)$ does not have any finite-dimensional spinorial representation.

This implicates that $\operatorname{GL}(N)$ owns infinite-dimensional spinorial representation. While in my opinion, a group's spinorial representation is the representation of its universal covering
group. And the connnected compenent of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ ($n>2$) group is not simply connected and its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So what group is its covering group?

My question:

1. Since the connnected compenent of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ ($n>2$) group is not simply connected and according to Lie's theorem, there exist a simple connnected Lie group whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ , then what's this covering group of  $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$?
   While I cannot imagine which group can cover the $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.
2. Now that $\operatorname{GL}(N)$ owns infinite-dimensional spinorial representation, can show me explicitly, or give me some reference which have solved this problem.

Comment: You don't need to know the covering group - every representation of the Lie algebra induces a representation of the universal cover, so it suffices to see that the algebra possess no "spinorial" representation (though I am not fully certain what "spinorial" means for groups that are not $\mathrm{SO}(1,n)$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I) Recall that since the Lie group $SO(N)\subset GL(N)$ is a proper subgroup of $GL(N)$, then functorially speaking, an irreducible representation of $GL(N)$ is also a (possible reducible) representation of $SO(N)$, but not necessarily the other way around.

When Ref. 1 states

> *There are no finite-dimensional spinorial representations of $GL(N)$,*

it means in this context that the finite-dimensional spinor representation of $SO(N)$ does not arise from a finite-dimensional representation of $GL(N)$.

II) For$^1$ $N>2$, the (double) [covering group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group) of the general linear group $$GL(N,\mathbb{R})~\cong~ \mathbb{R}_{>0}\times SL(N,\mathbb{R})$$ is the [metalinear group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metalinear+group) $ML(N,\mathbb{R})$. The metalinear group is a subgroup of the [metaplectic group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metaplectic+group) $Mp(2N,\mathbb{R})$ in twice the dimension. The reason that the metaplectic group $Mp(2N,\mathbb{R})$ has no non-trivial finite-dimensional representations is closely related to a similar [fact](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10230/2451) for the [Heisenberg Lie algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heisenberg+Lie+algebra).

References:

1. M. Kaku, *QFT,* 1993; p. 54. and p. 640.
2. M.B. Green, J.H. Schwarz and E. Witten, *Superstring theory,* Vol. 2, 1986; p. 272.

--

$^1$ $N=2$ is a special case, since $\pi_1(SL(2,\mathbb{R}),*)=\mathbb{Z}$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68333/2451) Phys.SE post and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2%28R%29) Wikipedia page.

Comment: Note for later: The above generalizes to other signatures of the metric.