# $\operatorname{GL}(4, R)$ group and Spinors in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mathematical-physics, spinors

Spinors are special representations of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ group which is double cover of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$. I am familiar with tetrad formalism and spin connection. $\operatorname{GL}(n,R)$ is not isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$.  In GR literatures,  it is usually said that $\operatorname{GL}(n,R)$ has not spinor representation. I don't understand what spinor representation of $\operatorname{GL}(n,R)$ is.
Can someone explain what it mean when we say $\operatorname{GL}(n,R)$ has not spinor representation.

Comment: [Asked and answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/121620)

Comment: @ACuriousMind thanks

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161744/2451