# Acting for a covariant derivative on charged spinor

Tags: general-relativity, fermions, differentiation, spinors

For field, theory what i know $i.e$,complex scalar QED
\begin{align}
D_\mu \phi =  \partial_{\mu} \phi - i Q A_{\mu} \phi
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
D_\mu \phi^{\dagger} = \partial_{\mu} \phi^{\dagger} + i Q A_{\mu} \phi^{\dagger}
\end{align}

In Geometry, by adapting vielbein formulation for spinor $\psi$,
\begin{align}
   D_\nu \psi = \partial_\nu \psi + \frac{1}{4} w_{\nu ab} \gamma^{[a} \gamma^{b]} \psi, \quad
   D_\nu \bar{\psi} = \partial_\nu \bar{\psi} - \frac{1}{4} w_{\nu ab} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{[a}\gamma^{b]}
\end{align}

Consider charged spinor, then the covariant derivatives

\begin{align}
  D_a \psi= e^{\mu}{}_a (\partial_\mu - i eQ A_\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^{bc} e_b{}^\nu \partial_\mu e_{c\nu})\psi, \quad \sigma^{ab} = \frac{\gamma^a \gamma^b - \gamma^b \gamma^a}{4}
\end{align}
Then how about $D_a \bar{\psi}$?

My guess is
\begin{align}
  D_a \bar{\psi}= e^{\mu}{}_a (\partial_\mu\bar{\psi} + i eQ A_\mu \bar{\psi} - \frac{1}{2} \bar{\psi}\sigma^{bc} e_b{}^\nu \partial_\mu e_{c\nu}), \quad \sigma^{ab} = \frac{\gamma^a \gamma^b - \gamma^b \gamma^a}{4}
\end{align}
Is this right?

Comment: Use the fact that $\bar \psi \psi$ is a scalar, apply the derivative and the Leibniz rule, it should be obvious enough

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161821/2451