# What's the field strength and energy density of a spinor field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors

The field strength and energy density of a vector field $A_\mu$ can be described using the field strength tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$.

What is the field strength and energy density associated with a (Dirac) spinor field $\Psi$?

Comment: The Dirac field do have an energy-momentum tensor, like the electromagnetic field.  However, its mathematical expression is very different and pretty complicated.

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86038/dirac-field-and-stress-energy-tensor-density?rq=1 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414556/energy-momentum-tensor-of-transformed-dirac-lagrangian?rq=1 and also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268619/stress-energy-tensor-for-dirac-fields-and-its-dependence-on-connection?rq=1 and again https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459895/energy-momentum-tensor-of-the-dirac-field?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the symmetric energy-momentum tensor of the *free* Dirac field:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
{T}_{\mu \nu}^{\textsf{D}} = i \, \frac{\hbar c}{4} \, \big( \, \bar{\Psi} \: \gamma_{\mu} \, (\, \partial_{\nu} \, \Psi \,) + \bar{\Psi} \: \gamma_{\nu} \, ( \, \partial_{\mu} \, \Psi \,) - (\, \partial_{\mu} \, \bar{\Psi} \,) \, \gamma_{\nu} \, \Psi - (\, \partial_{\nu} \, \bar{\Psi} \,) \, \gamma_{\mu} \, \Psi \, \big).
\end{equation}
This guy could be found using the *canonical* energy-momentum (or the Noether current associated to translation in spacetime), but it would need to be symmetrized using the complicated Belefante-Rosenfeld procedure.