# Energy-momentum tensor of a fermion

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm wondering how does one write the energy momentum tensor of a fermion (like an electron)? I've seen the formula for deriving it through the action. What I'm specifically asking is how would each of the 16 different components of the $T_{\mu\nu}$ of the fermion look like and what is the physics meaning for each of those components?

Comment: For curved spacetime see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161821/2451

Answer (score 2):

The energy-momentum tensor for a spinor is given by 
$T^{\mu\nu}=i\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi$.
Its components have the usual meaning, e.g.,
$T_{00}$ is energy density, etc.

To obtain it, just follow the usual definition: it is the Noether current of spacetime translations, given the spinor Lagrangian
${\cal L}=i\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi$.

More details can be found in every basic field theory textbook (Peskin & Schroeder...)